# Class-based DOM event delegation

Tags: javascript, events

Using CSS, it's very easy to attach a certain style for all elements sharing the same class. I would like to do something similar, but for DOM event handlers rather than styles. E.g. I'd like all elements with class `my-class` will have the same handler for a click event.

I know this can be done easily using a selector after the page is loaded, e.g. in jQuery:

```
$('.my-class').click(function() {alert('clicked');})
```

but I wonder if this can be achieved using DOM event delegation. The [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1688293/165753) suggests that delegation can be used to propagate an event from a child node to its parent (or ancestor, in general). Is it possible to define a handler on a single node with `my-class`, and have all the other elements with `my-class` delegate to it, even if they aren't descendents?

Comment: Are elements appended in DOM later  when `jQuery` has done its interpretation ? If _NO_, then you do not need event delegation...

Comment: yes, elements might be added later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although considered bad practice (because you should generally delegate to the nearest static ancestor), you can delegate to the `body` element as follows:

```
$('body').on('click', '.my-class', function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

This will of course delegate click events on any elements with a class of `my-class` that are in the `body` of your document.

Comment: Thanks, what would be a good practice to achieve this behavior then?

Comment: @dimid As I've said, bind to the nearest static ancestor (which in some cases may validly be `body`).

Answer (score 0):

We can also trigger the event when a different element is clicked:

```
$( "#other" ).click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).click();
});
```

Comment: Why bother? Event delegation is well documented; hacks like this are not required.